# Why doesn't setting the locale fix this UnicodeError?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, locale

I have the following Python script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys, locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.utf8')
print '肥皂' # This works
print u'肥皂'
```

When running the script I get:

```
肥皂
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../pycli/samples/x.py", line 5, in <module>
    print u'肥皂'
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(256)
```

However, when I explicitly set the LC_ALL environment variable in the shell then it works

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.utf8
```

So I'm wondering why doesn't the setlocale() have the same effect?

Comment: Did you try with 'en_US.utf-8'?

Comment: yep i tried that but with same results

Comment: did you try to .encode('utf-8') your output?

Comment: @ThomasOrozco that works, but then why don't I need it when i set the LC_ALL env variable

Comment: The environment variable is just an indication given to your script. When you give the information that utf-8 should be used, your will proceed so. I'll add more information in an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The value is only used to specify the default charset for output on interpreter startup. In other words, you're too late once the script is up and running.

Comment: In that case, why does the method exist? Looks like my only option is to manually set the environment variables..

Answer (score 1):

Unicode is like a conceptual idea of text that is only present inside your program.

It has the advantage that it can support any character, but the disadvantage that it can't be output as-is and must therefore be encoded to some encoding that can be displayed.

So, you want some input, it will be encoded and you will have to decode it, and if you want to output unicode, you have to encode it.

If you dont do it, python will try and do it for you (using ASCII, or what might be found in your env, as in your case), but you shouldnt rely on this, because python might get it wrong (as in your case).

Quite funnily, you can notice that in your case your terminal supports utf8, but that python didn't realize it could be using utf8.

Thats why you should *always* encode output and decode input (preferably using utf8 when possible !)

You can achieve this using the unicode encode method and the string decode method, giving them the encoding as argument.